# Applescript : text delimitation in a loop

Tags: loops, text, applescript

I'm trying to get values from a log file of all the occurrence of a value 
Recorded on the following key :

```
> <key>MyTime</key>         <string>2019-03-29T08:48:18+0000</string>
>       <key>serviceToken</key>
```

I can get the first occurrence of the value I want with the following code, but how can I search for more occurrence and add in secondary variable ?

```
##Getting the file name
set ShortDate to short date string of (current date)
set [dayN, MonthN, YearN] to the words of ShortDate
set myUSDate to YearN & MonthN & dayN as string
set myFileName to "TIME" & myUSDate & ".log"

set p to "/Users/kevin/Library/Logs/MyAPP/" & myFileName
set plistfile_path to POSIX file p

property leftEdge1 : "<key>myValueTime</key>"
property rightEdge1 : "<key>serviceToken</key>"
set myNewCaseNote to ""
set newFile to (plistfile_path as text)
set theSource to read file newFile as text
set theText to Unicode text
try
    set saveTID to text item delimiters
    set text item delimiters to leftEdge1
    set classValue to text item 2 of theSource
    set text item delimiters to rightEdge1
    set myCaseNote to text item 1 of classValue
    set text item delimiters to saveTID
    myCaseNote
end try
```

But how can I get other occurrence of this time/data ? And not only the first one

Comment: If the file is Property List or XML you are encouraged to use the capabilities of System Events to parse those formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should give you the direction. It's untested (im on mobile) but should work if no typos.

```
property leftEdge1 : "<key>myValueTime</key>"
property rightEdge1 : "<key>serviceToken</key>"


--Getting the file name
set ShortDate to short date string of (current date)
set [dayN, MonthN, YearN] to the words of ShortDate
set myUSDate to YearN & MonthN & dayN as string
set myFileName to "TIME" & myUSDate & ".log"

-- Read file
set p to "/Users/kevin/Library/Logs/MyAPP/" & myFileName
set plistfile_path to POSIX file p      
set newFile to (plistfile_path as text)
set theSource to read file newFile as text

-- Save text item delimiter
set saveTID to text item delimiters

-- First get all elements that start with leftEdge1
set text item delimiters to leftEdge1
set allContent to every text item of theSource
set text item delimiters to rightEdge1

set classValues to {}

-- Loop through text items and find content up to rightEdge1
repeat with singleContent in allContent
    set end of classValues to ((text item 1 of singleContent) as text)
end repeat

-- Restore text item delimiters
set text item delimiters to saveTID

classValues
```

Comment: Wow, that's perfect thank you , all the values are saved in classValues right? The only issue it's give me a  massive  value but the 3 occurrence that I was looking for are at the end of the file so I suppose I can trim the result, e.g :  [...] <string>51.9064</string>
  <key>longitude</key>
  <string>-8.5123</string>
  <key>note</key>
  <string></string>
  ", "2019-03-29T06:48:18+0000", "2019-03-29T12:56:10+0000", "2019-03-29T13:21:11+0000"}

Comment: I fix it with rest of classValues 
items 2 thru -1 of classValues  (the first item of the list is a long text) many thanks again